# navbar stick on reaching a scroll position 0 is not working

Tags: javascript, navbar

I read and tried several example of making a navbar stick on scrolling, but did not get success. I am using latest bootstrap template and cdn links, also established a link of js file. The example code was taken from w3school. I found nothing wrong in the code. Please leave some suggestions.
Here is my html, css and js respectively.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Open Schooling</h2>
  <p>Open Schooling is a necessaity.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">News</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Open Schooling</h3>
  <p>Many students are<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    Some text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to me that your code is working

Comment: But not working on my machine. I tried several times before posting on this platform. Can you please check it on your own machine and let me know the result.

Comment: It is strange that it is not working on my machine despite having no error. It works on this platform when I run code snippet. I linked the js.js file residing in the same folder using this line "<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>"

Comment: It is working on my machine: Windows 10 Pro ; Chrome latest. If you could post a URL where it is not working

Comment: If you haven't already, you should learn how to debug HTML/CSS/JavaScript in your Browser: Use the Developer Tools in Chrome or Firefox or etc. Here are some [Tips on the Chrome Developer Tools](https://javascript.info/debugging-chrome). You should especially look for any Errors in the Network tab and the (JavaScript) Console.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I got this result from debugging. On line no 4(var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;) it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null..."

Comment: Also similar message in line 10 (navbar.classList.remove("sticky");) like this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Classlist' of null" . Please help me finding out the root of the issue and also a solution.

Comment: When do you include your `<script>`? `<script>` position and order is important! There might not be a `#navbar` at that moment when you insert your `<script>` tag at the beginning of the document rather then at the end. Try to wrap your code with this: [VanillaJS DOMready](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-document-ready-plain-javascript/#plainjavascriptreadyalternative)

Comment: I visited your link. But found difficult to understand since i am not so familiar in js.

Comment: You should examine my first question in the last comment. What exactly is the position inside your HTML code, at which you import your JavaScript with a `<script>` tag. Is it in your `<head></head>` section? Or is it right before the closing `</body>` tag at the very end of your document? In your case the end of the document would be better.

Comment: Oh Sorry for misinterpretation of your answer. It's working after shifted the <script> tag to the bottom of the page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you explain me why this is happening, just for my knowledge.

Comment: Answer as "answer" :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem lies with the position of the `<script>` tag inside the HTML code. The issue was resolved after that `<script>` tag was shifted to the very end of the document, right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Why does this solve the issue?

A JavaScript code is executed right at that very position where it is inserted via the `<script>` tag. That means it will have to work with the exact circumstances and states that are known at that time. In this case the `<script>` tag was inserted before the `<div id="navbar">` was inserted in the code. From the JS's point of view, that `#navbar` element doesn't exist and thus `document.getElementById("navbar")` won't yield the expected result.

When you move the `<script>` tag to the end of the HTML code, or at least after the `<div id="navbar">` tag, this `#navbar` element is known to JavaScript at the time of execution and the code will work.

You can identify this issue with the JavaScript Console built into every modern browser (Desktop). In this case the error message was

> Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null

`null` in this case was the result of the query `document.getElementById("navbar")`. If you are sure, you didn't misspell the argument (`navbar`) [I assure myself of this, by copying and pasting those names in doubt], than it means, you have to work on the position of your `<script>` tag(s).

#### Addendum

If you cannot change the position of the `<script>` tag by whichever cause you can try to defer the code execution by wrapping your code inside a function and execute that function after the page loads. "Load" can hav different meanings:

1. HTML is fully loaded and the DOM is ready and complete to process on.
2. Any external content like images, style sheets and scripts are loaded

In case #1 there is an event called `DOMContentLoaded` you can react on and in case #2 the event is called `load`

See here for [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) and here for [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/load).

Comment: Your answer is a great chance for my knowledge. Thanks again. But one more issue arises now. I used a different function for shrinking the navbar on scroll. Now it is not working. The function of shrinking is kept above the other.

Comment: You should open a new issue for that, as this issue should be answered and the correct answer should be accepted by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the correct answer. You will award the correct answer 15 points of fame by that.

Comment: It's OK. Thanks.